# How to fix an UnboundLocalError caused due to a recursive function call in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer, clrs

I tried to convert the pseudo-code for the Maximum-Subarray problem given in Introduction to Algorithms By CLRS into a full-fledged working code in Python.

Code:

```
def cross(A,low,mid,high):
    left_sum = -float("inf")
    s = 0
    i = mid

    while (i >= low):
        s = s + A[i]
        if s > left_sum:
            left_sum = s
            max_left = i
        i = i - 1

    right_sum = -float("inf")
    s = 0
    j = mid + 1

    while (j < high):
        s = s + A[j]
        if s > right_sum:
            right_sum = s
            max_right = j
        j = j + 1

    return (max_left,max_right,left_sum+right_sum)

def maxSubarray(A,low,high):
    if high == low: return (low,high,A[low])
    else:
        mid = (low+high)/2
        (left_low,left_high,left_sum) = maxSubarray(A,low,mid)
        (right_low,right_high,right_sum) = maxSubarray(A,mid+1,high)
        (cross_low,cross_high,cross_sum) = cross(A,low,mid,high)

        if (left_sum >= right_sum & left_sum >= cross_sum):return (left_low,left_high,left_sum)
        elif (right_sum >= left_sum & right_sum >= cross_sum):return (right_low,right_high,right_sum)
        else: return (cross_low,cross_high,cross_sum)
t = [13,-3,-25,20,-3,-16,-23,18,20,-7,12,-5,-22,15,-4,7]

print maxSubarray(t,0,16)
```

When I try to run, I get this error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/suyash/Downloads/python/max_subarray.py", line 64, in <module>
    print maxSubarray(t,0,16)
  File "/home/suyash/Downloads/python/max_subarray.py", line 49, in maxSubarray
    (left_low,left_high,left_sum) = maxSubarray(A,low,mid)
  File "/home/suyash/Downloads/python/max_subarray.py", line 49, in maxSubarray
    (left_low,left_high,left_sum) = maxSubarray(A,low,mid)
  File "/home/suyash/Downloads/python/max_subarray.py", line 49, in maxSubarray
    (left_low,left_high,left_sum) = maxSubarray(A,low,mid)
  File "/home/suyash/Downloads/python/max_subarray.py", line 49, in maxSubarray
    (left_low,left_high,left_sum) = maxSubarray(A,low,mid)
  File "/home/suyash/Downloads/python/max_subarray.py", line 53, in maxSubarray
    (cross_low,cross_high,cross_sum) = cross(A,low,mid,high)
  File "/home/suyash/Downloads/python/max_subarray.py", line 39, in cross
    return (max_left,max_right,left_sum+right_sum)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max_right' referenced before assignment
```

How can I fix this? Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The problematic variable is assigned inside an if statement; just make sure you assign it a default value *before* (and outside) an if statement. The same goes for `max_left`, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two really small mistakes:

1. Your **list** i.e., `t` is of length 16. This means last index is 15. Thus call `maxSubarray(t,0,15)` not `maxSubarray(t,0,16)`
2. `while (j <= high)`. Loop until `j<= high` not until `j<high`

Also with these two fixes, you don't need to set any default values to `max_right` or `max_right`. The `while` any `if` conditionals will always be True in every recursive call.

Demo:

```
>>> def cross(A,low,mid,high):
...     left_sum = -float("inf")
...     s = 0
...     i = mid
...     while (i >= low):
...         s = s + A[i]
...         if s > left_sum:
...             left_sum = s
...             max_left = i
...         i = i - 1
...     right_sum = -float("inf")
...     s = 0
...     j = mid + 1
...     while (j <= high):  # Loop until j<= high not until j<high
...         s = s + A[j]
...         if s > right_sum:
...             right_sum = s
...             max_right = j
...         j = j + 1
...     return (max_left,max_right,left_sum+right_sum)
... 
>>> def maxSubarray(A,low,high):
...     if high == low: return (low,high,A[low])
...     else:
...         mid = (low+high)/2
...         (left_low,left_high,left_sum) = maxSubarray(A,low,mid)
...         (right_low,right_high,right_sum) = maxSubarray(A,mid+1,high)
...         (cross_low,cross_high,cross_sum) = cross(A,low,mid,high)
...         if (left_sum >= right_sum & left_sum >= cross_sum):return (left_low,left_high,left_sum)
...         elif (right_sum >= left_sum & right_sum >= cross_sum):return (right_low,right_high,right_sum)
...         else: return (cross_low,cross_high,cross_sum)
... 
>>> t = [13,-3,-25,20,-3,-16,-23,18,20,-7,12,-5,-22,15,-4,7]
>>> print maxSubarray(t,0,15)  # Last index = 15 not 16
(7, 10, 43)  # This shows max subarray is from index 7 to 10 i.e., [18,20,-7,12] and the sum is 43
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Thank you. One more question though. When I just ran the **cross** function, the code `print cross(t,0,8,16)` worked without giving any errors. Why is that so?

Comment: You are not getting error at first recursive call `(0,8,16)`, but at 4th i.e., 2nd call -> `(0,4,8)`, 3rd call -> `(0,2,4)`, 4th call -> `(0,1,2)`. At this call you have `j=mid+1` i.e., = 2 and `while (j < high)` is `False` as 2<2 is `False`. So `max_left` is not set and you get an ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to account for boundary conditions.

There may come a point when a conditional that normally succeeds suddenly fails, leaving a variable unbound. You need to make sure that the variable has a sane default regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You only ever assign `max_right` in an `if` statement inside a `while` loop, meaning that if you get the exception, then either `s > right_sum` or `j < high` was *never* true:

```
while (j < high):
    s = s + A[j]
    if s > right_sum:
        right_sum = s
        max_right = j
    j = j + 1
```

You should give `max_right` a default value *outside* that `while` loop; `max_right = high` would be appropriate here.